# Export constraints and inverse kinematics

Tags: export, constraints, file-format

Is it possible to export constraints (for example limit rotation constrains) and inverse kinematics from blender? These exports would be imported into WorldViz to interact with the object in virtual reality(No fixed animations).

Which file-format would I need to use?

Optional:

Is there a way to export to `cmfx`? (This file-format is used by WorldViz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FBX or collada can bake effects of the constraints while exporting animations, that’s all. There is no way to export constraint/IK systems themselves, afaik.

Further more, I’m not sure that would make sense at all, seeing how hard it is already to support basics of exchange between applications that all have different ways of handling common topics (referring to animation and armatures e.g.), I would suspect things rather complex and advanced like constraints to be a plain nightmare.

Comment: Well this makes a lot more sense to me. I edited my question with the exact usage of my problem. Seems like I will have to program the behaviors and limitations myself.

Comment: Note that for specific and well-defined needs, you may 'wrap' this inside a common format. E.g. FBX supports exporting custom properties of objects, so you could define a basic text-based "format" for the constraints you need, write this in some object's custom property, and on WorldViz side read those custom props and regenerate constraints from them. Just an idea, that may be simpler to implement than a full new exporter.