# Is there a way to export a rigged model with animation with IK from Blender to C4D?

Tags: armature, export, keyframes

I'm used to modeling and animating in Blender, but I need to render my scene in Cinema4D. I tried Collada and .fbx export, but only my controller keeps its animation; once the model and the rig are imported in Cinema4D.
I don't know if it's possible, or if I'm missing something, but is there a way to export a rigged model with animation with IK from Blender to Cinema4D ?

Thx in advance !

Comment: See this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28452/export-constraints-and-inverse-kinematics. Your best option is to bake the animation into a .mdd file.

Comment: Thx. Actually, one option I thought, was to find a way to apply the bone-driven animation to all the object of my scene, in order that they each have their own individual keyframes. Doing that isn't possible ?